# PHP SDK For AWS S3 Using ARN Bucket for Auth

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We're using the latest PHP AWS S3 SDK.

We've been given a ARN Bucket name
eg:

`arn:aws:s3:::project-s3-eu-west-2-d-app-uploads`

Using the PHP Code, we're trying:

```
<?php 

    
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

    $s3 = new S3Client([
        'version'     => 'latest',
        'region'      => 'eu-west-2',
        'use_arn_region' => TRUE, //  or FALSE
    ]);

    $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => 'arn:aws:s3:::project-s3-eu-west-2-d-app-uploads',
//      'Bucket' => 'project-s3-eu-west-2-d-app-uploads.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com', // this did not work 
        'Key'    => 'random-unique-name.ext',
        'Body'   => fopen('/local/file/path/name.ext', 'r'),
        'ACL'    => ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
    ]);

?>
```

But - no matter what we try, we get the following error:

```
Bucket parameter parsed as ARN and failed with: Provided ARN was not a valid S3 access point ARN or S3 Outposts access point ARN.
```

Have you used an ARN for auth, not a Key/Secret?
Thanks

Comment: Try defining the 'Bucket' with the bucket's URL rather than ARN. For all my S3 SDK integrations, I use the Bucket URL without problem. But I'm not sure if this is your issue or something else going on. Worth a try.

Comment: Why does the SDK seem to think you passed the bucket name as ARN? It's not an ARN from what I see

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the example with the right ARN for the bucket name, and tried the bucket URL. 
This didn't work.